# log4j2 xml Configuration tag dest attribute example

Tags: log4j2

Has anyone a working example using the `dest` attribute to output log4j2 debug information to a file?  I am trying to troubleshoot configuration problems and see the documentation shows this property can be set to err, or a url, or a file path along with setting the `status` to the level of output to produce, but I am not able to find a working example anywhere for this particular property.

Presently my xml for the Configuration element is as follows:

```
<Configuration status="DEBUG" dest="${sys:catalina.home}/logs/log4jdebug.log">
```

But, alas, no log4jdebug.log file is appearing along with the files my `RollingFile` appender create in the same path.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not found a specific example, but you can obtain equivalent functionality by putting

```
dest="err"
```

where output will appear in std.out.  With a Tomcat web app, for example, output from log4j will write to catalina.out.

I was able to troubleshoot my configuration by setting `status="debug"` along with `dest="err"`.